# Android "gps requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" error, even though my manifest file contains this

Tags: java, android, gps

Each time I run the application, my SecurityException gets thrown and the error from the debugger reads as so:

java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

This seems like a simple mistake, however, my manifest file is completely correct. Here it is, and here is my MapActivity code as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.dev.cromer.jason.coverme.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value= "@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

My Activity:

```
    package com.dev.cromer.jason.coverme;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }



    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                //mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (myLocation != null) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Not null");
            }
            else {
                Log.d("TAG", "NULL");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.d("TAG", "SE CAUGHT");
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("CHANGED", "LOCATION UPDATED");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Comment: On what version of Android are you testing this?

Comment: Unrelated, but if you request fine location you don't need to request coarse.  It's included.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are all part of [the Android 6.0 runtime permission system](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html). In addition to having them in the manifest as you do, you *also* have to request them from the user at runtime (using `requestPermissions()`) and see if you have them (using `checkSelfPermission()`).

One workaround in the short term is to drop your `targetSdkVersion` below 23.

But, eventually, you will want to update your app to use the runtime permission system.

For example, this activity works with five permissions. Four are runtime permissions, though it is presently only handling three (I wrote it before `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was added to the runtime permission roster).

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2015 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.permmonger;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS={
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
  };
  private static final String[] CAMERA_PERMS={
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
  };
  private static final String[] CONTACTS_PERMS={
      Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
  };
  private static final String[] LOCATION_PERMS={
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
  };
  private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST=1337;
  private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST=INITIAL_REQUEST+1;
  private static final int CONTACTS_REQUEST=INITIAL_REQUEST+2;
  private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST=INITIAL_REQUEST+3;
  private TextView location;
  private TextView camera;
  private TextView internet;
  private TextView contacts;
  private TextView storage;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    location=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location_value);
    camera=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.camera_value);
    internet=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.internet_value);
    contacts=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.contacts_value);
    storage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.storage_value);

    if (!canAccessLocation() || !canAccessContacts()) {
      requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, INITIAL_REQUEST);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    updateTable();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.camera:
        if (canAccessCamera()) {
          doCameraThing();
        }
        else {
          requestPermissions(CAMERA_PERMS, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
        return(true);

      case R.id.contacts:
        if (canAccessContacts()) {
          doContactsThing();
        }
        else {
          requestPermissions(CONTACTS_PERMS, CONTACTS_REQUEST);
        }
        return(true);

      case R.id.location:
        if (canAccessLocation()) {
          doLocationThing();
        }
        else {
          requestPermissions(LOCATION_PERMS, LOCATION_REQUEST);
        }
        return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    updateTable();

    switch(requestCode) {
      case CAMERA_REQUEST:
        if (canAccessCamera()) {
          doCameraThing();
        }
        else {
          bzzzt();
        }
        break;

      case CONTACTS_REQUEST:
        if (canAccessContacts()) {
          doContactsThing();
        }
        else {
          bzzzt();
        }
        break;

      case LOCATION_REQUEST:
        if (canAccessLocation()) {
          doLocationThing();
        }
        else {
          bzzzt();
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  private void updateTable() {
    location.setText(String.valueOf(canAccessLocation()));
    camera.setText(String.valueOf(canAccessCamera()));
    internet.setText(String.valueOf(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)));
    contacts.setText(String.valueOf(canAccessContacts()));
    storage.setText(String.valueOf(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)));
  }

  private boolean canAccessLocation() {
    return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));
  }

  private boolean canAccessCamera() {
    return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA));
  }

  private boolean canAccessContacts() {
    return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS));
  }

  private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
    return(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED==checkSelfPermission(perm));
  }

  private void bzzzt() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_bzzzt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  private void doCameraThing() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_camera, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  private void doContactsThing() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_contacts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  private void doLocationThing() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/PermissionMonger))

> For the requestPermissions() function, should the parameters just be "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"? Or should I include the full name "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"?

I would use the constants defined on `Manifest.permission`, as shown above.

> Also, what is the request code?

That will be passed back to you as the first parameter to `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, so you can tell one `requestPermissions()` call from another.

Comment: For the requestPermissions() function, should the parameters just be "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"? Or should I include the full name "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"?

Comment: Thank you, this got rid of the error. I am still having trouble accessing my location, as my locationManager keeps returning my location as null, but that is not relevant to this bug. 
Thank you for your solution!

Comment: @CommonsWare : What you mean by saying 'eventually' ? Sorry, I don't get that part.

Comment: @theapache64: Someday, something is going to cause you to want to set your `targetSdkVersion` to 23 or higher. At that point, you will need to adopt the runtime permission system. Until that time comes around, you are welcome to keep your `targetSdkVersion` below 23 and ignore runtime permissions.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Now i got it. :)

Comment: @CommonsWare I am Using your code for access location permission in my app. I used ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. But i am getting this error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 8 bits for requestCode

How to Come through this

Comment: @PraveenKumar: My guess is that you are extending `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`, which have this limitation, IIRC.

Comment: @CommonsWare If I decrease my targetSDK version below 23 then it works but if I manually go and deny the location permission from app settings then app is crashing with SecurityException. Even permission Check is coming as granted in that case. Any solution for that scenario.

Comment: @abhishek: "but if I manually go and deny the location permission from app settings then app is crashing with SecurityException" -- hmmmm... it is supposed to be just declining to give you a location. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] (stack trace with the exception and the code that triggers the exception).

Answer (score 41):

My simple solution is this

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_permission_map, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

or you can open permission dialog in else like this

```
} else {
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION }, 
      TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
}
```

Comment: laways move in to else part bro :(

Comment: add dialog to add permissions in this "else", and you are good to go.

Comment: This is in fact without a doubt the fix for Android 6.  It should be noted you must put the permission requests in the else.

Comment: I got this error with Target SDK as 22 and on Android 5.1 on device S plus (GiONEE_WBL7511). I am confused on why this crash happened. Any clues?
java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.

Answer (score 5):

CAUSE: "Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app." In this case, "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" is a "dangerous permission and for that reason, you get this 'java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.' error (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

SOLUTION: Implementing the code provided at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html under the "Request the permissions you need" and "Handle the permissions request response" headings.