# Android Studio setmylocationenabled(true) throws SecurityException

Tags: java

I've encountered a problem. My program throes SecurityException, even if I declraed all the Permissions.
Here is MapsActivity class:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);}
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    try{
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);


    // set map type

}
```

Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mazebug.danuleoshaleosha">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Interface" />
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main22Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".SFR_Table" />
    <activity android:name=".sfrtable2" />
    <activity android:name=".sfrtable3" />
    <activity android:name=".sfrtable4" />
    <activity android:name=".sfrtable5" />
    <activity android:name=".sfrtable6" />
    <activity android:name=".sfrtable7" />
    <activity android:name=".mySfrs" />
    <activity android:name=".Search_bySiteName" />
    <activity android:name=".Search_byDate" />
    <activity android:name=".Search_byLocation" />
    <activity android:name=".Found_1" />
    <activity android:name=".Found_2" />
    <activity android:name=".Found_3" />
    <activity android:name=".Edit_first" />
    <activity android:name=".Edit_1_2" />
    <activity android:name=".Edit_1_3" />
    <activity android:name=".Edit_1_4" />
    <activity android:name=".Edit_1_5" />
    <activity android:name=".Edit_1_6" />
    <activity android:name=".Edit_1_7" />
    <activity android:name=".testing" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".Main23Activity" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA-z6nM3WoXwP7dBzIdz1_dssl8X81xttg" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
</application>
```

Here is the thrown Exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                              Process: mazebug.danuleoshaleosha, PID: 13162
                                                                      java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.c(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.onTransact(SourceFile:274)
                                                                          at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at mazebug.danuleoshaleosha.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:51)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.be.a(SourceFile:82)
                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I'm pretty confused, 'cause it seems like I granted the required permissions.
Please give me a piece of advice. Thanks!

Comment: refer this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083913/android-gps-requires-access-fine-location-error-even-though-my-manifest-file) and [docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/permissions/declaring.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try change the code.

```
// Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return;
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```