# runtime permissions in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-permissions

Thanks to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/32084038/1979882
I found that I have to ask the user if he/she grants my app to retrieve the location. Ok, this work for `android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in Android 6.0 or it will show this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.app/my.pack.mActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: "network" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

But in my application there are several permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ru.ps.vm.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Which of them are needed `requestPermissions()` method to ask the user?

Comment: Here are the "dangerous" permissions which require explicit approval in Marshmallow: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: @KenWolf , thanks. That's it