# I am trying to get the GPS coordinates from within a fragment. I am not getting any errors but the application crashes on launch

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, gps

I think there is a problem in My `Location Listener` but I am not able to pinpoint it. When I remove the code to get GPS my application is working fine.

```
public class RescueFragment extends Fragment{

    public RescueFragment(){}
    private static final long mindisch=1;
    private static final long mintim=1000;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected Double latitude,longitude;

    TextView alert_display;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rescue, container, false);
        alert_display = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.alert_display);       
        btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_rescue_me);

        locationManager =(LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,mindisch,mintim, new MyLocationListener()   );

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                alert_display.setText("Alert Sent to User");
                showCurrentLocation();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation()
    {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location!=null)
        {
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
            longitude=location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Alert sent. Location: "+ latitude+" "+ longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
            longitude=location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Alert sent. Location: "+ latitude+" "+ longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Provider Status Changed: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GPS ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GPS OFF:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly post the error log .

Comment: did you add the permission to fetch location in your manifest file??

Comment: yes i did add permission in mainfest

Comment: 05-02 13:07:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(15930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 13:07:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(15930): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 15930
05-02 13:07:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(15930): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
05-02 13:07:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(15930):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)

Comment: This is permission exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this `Permissions` in your Manifest.**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

For `Android Versions 6.0` you need to allow user's to give `Runtime Permissions`.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_permission_map, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

Comment: Are you having compiled `SDK` Version 6.0  ? if Yes then you need to allow user to have `Runtime Permission` in your app. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083913/android-gps-requires-access-fine-location-error-even-though-my-manifest-file

Comment: i did add it before the application tag.. should i change it position?

Comment: Not need to change position. Check my comment above. Are you using Android 6.0 version?