# Check runtime permission on android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I used `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);`   to check my app has location permission or not.This method returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` which is correct answer.Now I go to my app's settings and disable location permision.Now also the above method returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`. But it should `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`.Can anyone give me some idea in this matter?If I can use another method what is it?

Comment: are you sure you are using marshmallow device

Comment: you are checking this status in onCreate or onResume

Comment: Could you post your code? I mean,  the code of `onRequestPermissionsResult`..

Comment: @ankit Yes I am using marshmalow device

Comment: @vishal I checked this status in onCreate .Is anything wrong?

Comment: @Homen This happening might be you havn't kill you app, and open setting then disable location permission, again open activity, but in onresume you havn't check as oncreate is not called so its returning true

Comment: @mani I am not imeplemented onRequestPermissionsResult yet.It is only Handle the permissions request response.Is not it?

Comment: @Homen What is your target SDK? 23 or below 23?

Comment: @Mani it is 22.Should I change it to 23

Comment: @Homen Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, the target sdk is 22. So the method `checkSelfPermission` always gives you permission as `Granted`. If you want to implement Runtime permission, you have to change it to 23.

If you want detail answer, [please refer SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083913/android-gps-requires-access-fine-location-error-even-though-my-manifest-file). Read all comments.

Answer (score 3):

To request permission

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) 
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
  requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and to check if user has accepted your request override the following code

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case YOUR_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                // permission was granted
            } else {
                // permission denied
                //Disable the functionality 
                //that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Ref :http://sourabhkarkal.com/blogspot/requesting-permissions-in-android-m/

Comment: I am also using this code.But after disable permission from app settings it return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED.After disable it should be PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED.Is not it?

Comment: On your activity OnResume method do checkSelfPermission() and tell me the result