# App crashes due to missing permission request

Tags: android, permissions, crash, geolocation

I have received the following runtime exception in the crash reporting section of Firebase:

> java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32084038/7201671) states, the exception can be solved by requesting the permissions at runtime.

Yet, what actually bugs me is the fact that in my Manifest file I only request **COARSE LOCATION** permission, while **FINE LOCATION** is never there.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    ... // other permissions
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    ... // no sign of fine location
```

**Why would a missing permission throw such an exception?**

Notes: This is the first time the app crashes since it has been launched. The crash took place on an ALLVIEW VivaH7 API 19 with Android 4.4.2. 
(no similar crashes on any other devices or API's yet)

Also, is **COARSE LOCATION** considered a dangerous permission as well as **FINE LOCATION**? Therefore, should I request permission for **COARSE LOCATION** at runtime?

Comment: You can't use the gps provider with only course location.  If you're using gps, you must request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.  If you don't need gps and can get by with only network location, then you can use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

Comment: @DanielNugent I understand, I was somehow remembering them the other way round, therefore the fault. Thanks and sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` both are dangerous permission.

> Either ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is required when you are getting location from
>   NetworkProvider.

While,

> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is required when you are getting location from
>   GpsProvider.

So if you are getting location from `NetworkProvider` as well as `GpsProvider`, you have to add `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission also in your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Why? As long as I need a rough approximation of my users' location I see no point in adding another permission. And my question remains, why is the app crashing due to the absence of permission that is not stated in the manifest in the first place?

Comment: Check my answer @CatalinGhita

Comment: As I said above, I was somehow remembering them the other way round. Therefore the fault, thanks!

Comment: You have to wait 2 more minutes. I tried already, it appears you've been too fast haha

Comment: Apparently, I cannot approve an answer this fast. It is SO's policy. Now I should be able to do it